# C# получить время кадра любого приложения, использующего GPU

Tags: c#, c++, c, directx, gpu

Хочу написать программу, которая будет проверять частоту кадров любого приложения. Моей целью является залогировать **FPS** и **время каждого кадра**. Я написал такое приложение, он оно использует API программы Rivatuner Statistics Server и без нее не работает.

Существую ли готовые решения в виде DLL для получении информации о кадрах сторонних приложений?

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать посредством Windows Event Tracing, подписываясь на соответствующие события. В качестве референсной реализации можно посмотреть [PresentMon](https://github.com/GameTechDev/PresentMon). Собственно вашу программу можно даже не писать, так как это все уже реализовано в PresentMon.